# Android checkbox state based background color?

Tags: android, android-styles, android-checkbox

First of all I am not able to find the styling API documentation for check box at  Android developer site. I want to make following change to the check box. Currently my checkbox when checked appears like : [image]

I want to change color behind the white check mark to other color like :

[image]

Is there any styling feature or attribute to achieve this ?

Comment: go with rami comment. it will work. colorAcent is the property in style, which give selected color to checkbox.

Comment: Have you solved this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

```
       android:buttonTint="@color/CHECK_COLOR"
       (OR)
       android:button="@drawable/your_check_drawable"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Material theme it will automatically manage according to primary color of theme. or you can manage according to you with help of custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this programmatically

```
boolean checked =false;

checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if(checked){
        GradientDrawable d=new GradientDrawable();
        d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        checkbox.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        }
    else{
        GradientDrawable d=new GradientDrawable();
        d.setColor(Color.RED);
        checkbox.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    }
    checked = !checked
    }

});
```

You will have access to many properties of GradientDrawable class to stylize your background. you can see more at [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html)